# Screen Receiver Broadcast not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

i want to receive a broad cast when the screen is turned off in android. I have written the following code.  This is the Receiver's code.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    helper = new FeedReaderDBHelper(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        System.out.println("Screen Off Receiver just received something");
        if(helper.getValue(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.onlock).equals("YES"))
        {

            helper.lockAll();
            wasScreenOn = false;
        }
        else if(helper.getValue(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.onLock3).equals("YES"))
        {
            System.out.println("Running 3 minutes thread");
            Runner runner = new Runner(context);
            Thread t = new Thread(runner);
            t.setName("LockThreeThread");

            t.start();
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // and do whatever you need to do here
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
}
```

I am registering and unregistering the Receiver in a Service. The code is as follows.

Registring Receiver in onStartCommand method

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    RegisterReceiver();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //System.out.println("StartRemove");
    helper = new FeedReaderDBHelper(this);
    names = helper.getNames();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startChecker();
        }
    });
    t.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And this is how i unregister in onDestroy of the Service method.

```
private void RegisterReceiver()
{
    receiver = Factory.getScreeReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Please let me know what could be the problem. I have been digging into it for long time. Last two days were wasted on this. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Use background color with alpha

Comment: Where are you starting the service from? Is the Activity which the service is getting started from getting run at all?

Comment: @TharakaDevinda  I start the service from main activity and yes activity and service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overly complicating this.
This is the activity you would need

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(startServiceIntent);

}
```

This is the service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("APP", "Service started");
    ScreenOffReceiver receiver = new ScreenOffReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));

    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

And this is the Broadcast Receiver

```
public class ScreenOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public ScreenOffReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("APP", "EVENT occured");
    }
}
```

I just tried out this code and the logging worked fine.

When you start this via a service, and start a new thread to do the job in the onStartCommand() method, be noted that the thread will start every time you invoke the onCreate() of the activity.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. What was the problem? I don't understand why there was any problem? If you could guide me.

Comment: I think that factory you coded did something with it. Anyway, just keeping things simple makes things work easier. And you're welcome.